# Slower Java Asynchronous Client run after about one hour

Tags: java, sockets, asynchronous

I tried to connect with asynchronous socket and read new messages once per second.

I used sample client code (http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Java_Network/0080__Java_Network_Asynchronous_Socket_Channels.htm) and in `getTextFromUser` method I added `sleep` method (with 1000 ms) and removed read command from user.

Additionally I added additional logic in `ReadWriteHandler` method. It started work great, but after about one hour program was suspended and has worked (execute my additional logic) not once per second but one per about 10 minutes.

Do you have any idea what might happen?

Part of code:

```
public void ConnectAsynchr() {


 try {   


     this.channel = AsynchronousSocketChannel.open();
    SocketAddress serverAddr = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", PortNumberAsynchr);
    Future<Void> result = channel.connect(serverAddr);

    try {
        result.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    this.writeLog("ConnAsynch", "Asynchronous connection succesful established", true);

    this.connectAsynch = true;
    this.attach = new Attachment();
    this.attach.channel = this.channel;
    this.attach.buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(16384);
    this.attach.isRead = false;
    this.attach.mainThread = Thread.currentThread();


    ReadWriteHandler readWriteHandler = new ReadWriteHandler();
    this.channel.write(this.attach.buffer, this.attach, readWriteHandler);

    try {
        this.attach.mainThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        this.writeLog("ERROR", e.toString(), false);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


 }
 catch (IOException e) {
     this.writeLog("ERROR", e.toString(), false);
     System.out.println(e);

 }

}



class Attachment {
  AsynchronousSocketChannel channel;
  ByteBuffer buffer;
  Thread mainThread;
  boolean isRead;
}
class ReadWriteHandler implements CompletionHandler<Integer, Attachment> {
  @Override
  public void completed(Integer result, Attachment attach) {
    if (attach.isRead) {
      attach.buffer.flip();
      Charset cs = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
      int limits = attach.buffer.limit();
      byte bytes[] = new byte[limits];
      attach.buffer.get(bytes, 0, limits);
      String msg = new String(bytes, cs);


      writeLog("Asynchr Msg rec", msg, false);



      AsynchrMessLogic(msg);



      try {
        msg = this.getTextFromUser();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      if (msg.equalsIgnoreCase("bye")) {
        attach.mainThread.interrupt();
        return;
      }

       attach.buffer.clear();
      byte[] data = msg.getBytes(cs);
      attach.buffer.put(data);
      attach.buffer.flip();
      attach.isRead = false; // It is a write
      attach.channel.write(attach.buffer, attach, this);
    }else {
      attach.isRead = true;
      attach.buffer.clear();
      attach.channel.read(attach.buffer, attach, this);
    }
  }
  @Override
  public void failed(Throwable e, Attachment attach) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  private String getTextFromUser() throws Exception{
    /*System.out.print("\nPlease enter a  message  (Bye  to quit):");
    BufferedReader consoleReader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String msg = consoleReader.readLine();
    */
    Thread.sleep(threadSleep);
    String msg="aaa";
    return msg;
  }
}
```

Comment: Each time you establishing connection, you join to main thread. Doing this means you will eventually run out of available IO descriptors, which is probably exactly what's happening. Scratch your example, do you _actually_ know why does it recommend you to join with main thread?

Comment: I'm new in this subject and I use example code. I don't know what for join with main thread, but I establish connection only one time when running program.